# Is it possible to detect if the browser has rendered anything?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine you have an empty iframe on a page. You are given a `<script .. />` tag which you write out to the iframe. The script tag could be doing anything and everything. Is it possible to detect in any way whether anything at all is visible/displayed inside the iframe? I don't mean visibility value and I don't mean whether the elements are 'in view'. I mean to detect that there's actually something displayed on screen. The script could open 3 other iframes and the last iframe displays an image.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "visible", which could need a bit of explanation. A white 1x1 image on a white background is technically a visible element but not visible to the human eye.

Comment: Whew, that's a broad one. Maybe you could watch for actual [paint events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformancePaintTiming)? Except the support isn't great.

Comment: This also sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Tell us what you aim to do, alternative solutions may be available. (This question sounds like ad impression detection/anti-content blocker).

Comment: This is a problem in the online advertising domain. The script tag is the actual creative tag - the ad itself - that you might get from your clients and you want to display inside the iframe. The challenge to figure out is when something became really visible inside the iframe.